# Selecting an (already open) application on my taskbar to bring it to front and in focus, frequently doesn't work

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

Windows 11, this has been happening since I installed it.
I have many applications pinned and running. Nothing out of the ordinary of course.
When I click the icon in the taskbar, it puts a square around the icon, and looks like it tried to open it but then does nothing. I have to click on it a second time and occasionally a third or fourth time for it to actually bring the application into focus and into view.

This is for already open applications only. Its as though they are in a sleep state as they haven't been visible for a while, and it can't bring them up til they are awoken or something.

Is there a solution to this? I can't find anything anywhere.

Edit:
I have recorded a short video showing the issue. The foreground application is my browser, viewing this page. I haven't had visual studio (purple icon) open in the foreground (though the application is very much already open), for some time. It is positioned behind my browser. Clicking it once, should bring it to the foreground. However as you see, I click it and it flashes gently with a darker coloured square. The app never comes to foreground. I am required to click it a second time for it to come to foreground, and hence cover up the browser. Here is the video: https://youtu.be/ebs--xWOXCg

Comment: Right click on the Task Bar for Settings.  Put the Task Bar to the Left and then make sure Select Far Corner to Show Desktop has been enabled.  That is all you can do natively and the Windows 10 tricks and settings went to the dustbin.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I was talking about. Apps aren't responding to my click asking to bring them into focus immediately.

Comment: I've added a video showing this happen, as detailed in my edit.

Comment: Hopefully someone using Windows 11 has an answer for you. I looked at both my Windows 11 Pro machines.

Comment: There have been a number of issues with Windows 11 Taskbar, e.g., https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/12/28/microsoft-is-trying-to-fix-windows-11-taskbar-issues/ . Perhaps this is another. Post on a Microsoft forum to see what progress has been made.